# Passing specific parameter to MEF importing constructor depending on export metadata

Tags: c#, mef

I want to compose my application with some extension assemblies by MEF. Thereby any number of exports of type T can exist in an extension assembly and I have to export different constructor parameter values to each export depending on the export metadata it has. In this connection I want to use lazy initialization.

Can please anyone help me how I can do this?

Thank you.